# I am trying to find best way to display a error box with errors in springs

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to find best way to display a error box with errors in springs.

I like to display that error under each field in question. Below is my code but I would think it would be easyer some other way?

```
<c:set var="validationErrorsContent"><form:errors path="content"/></c:set>
<c:if test="${not empty validationErrorsContent}">
<font color="red">
    <div id="error" class="error">
             <form:errors path="content" cssClass="error" />
    </div>
</font>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print all error by using

```
<form:errors path="*"/>
```

you apply this at your jsp page like this if you also apply customize validation than

```
<c:if test="${success=='n'}">
   <form:errors path="*"/>
</c:if>
```

and set "success" at your controller for `map.put("success", "n");`

Comment: the issue with this is that the errors dont show up in the order of the fields on the screen